# Ef core query based on non primitive type primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have an aggregate root with a non primitve type primary key :

```
public class Category : AggregateRoot<CategoryId>
{
    // some properties
}

public class CategoryId : ValueObject<CategoryId>
{
    public Guid Identity { get; private set; }
}
```

And my entity configuration :

```
  public class CategoryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Category> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            builder.Property(x => x.Id)
                .HasConversion(
                    v => v.Identity,
                    v => new CategoryId(v));

            builder.ToTable("Categories");
        }
  }
```

I have no problem in insert new data but when I want to receive data from database with following code, I received an error from Ef core 3.1.4 :

```
var categories = _context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(category=> category.Id.Identity == "someId");

Error :  failed The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Category>
          .Where(t => t.Id.Identity == __categoryId_0)' could not be translated.
```

How can I receive data from database without need to change my primary key to a primitive type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solve the problem using comparing aggregate Id with a new valueobject in the FirstOrDefault:

```
 var category = _context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c=> c.Id == new CategoryId("someId"));
```